# When you change the value of a variable in a .js file from a .html file, is it possible for the value to be retained in another .html file?

Tags: javascript, html

say I have 2 separate HTML files accessing variables on a JS file, can I retain the value of the variable after I change it on the HTML file?

say this is my javascript file, lets call it variables.js

```
//a variable to change
var number = 10;
```

say this is one of my HTML files, lets call it test1.html

```
<script src="variables.js" type="text/javascript">
number;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
number = 20;

//here it would print 20 to the console
console.log(number);
</script>
```

and say this is my second HTML file, lets call it test2.html

```
<script src="variables.js" type="text/javascript"
number;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//when i console.log it, it would output 10 instead of 20
console.log(number);
</script>
```

Is there a way to get around this?

In my project there are more than 2 files, so I am just trying to retain the value of the variable in each HTML file when changed.

Any help would be appreciated thanks :D

Comment: You may want to use `Window.localStorage` for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: ok ill check it out man, thanks

Comment: To store and retrieve more complicated objects, you will have to do something like this: `localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify(object));` and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject'));`